# Saison fermentation. White residue and thin film. Infected?

Tags: fermentation, saison

I'm ferementing a saison with Wyeast 3724, and after the initial ferment, it died down, I then bought it into a warmer room and chucked some blankets over it (I'm also using an aquarium heater, but that alone wasn't working). I checked on it last night, and it seems to have fleks of white on top, as well as a thin film. The smell is also rather funky (I guess this is usual for a Saison). Here's what it looks like:

[image: Saison film]

Is this usual for a saison, or have I got an infection on my hands?

Comment: Luckily for you, saisons are a style that when (properly) soured, can turn out fantastic.  If you don't mind tying up your bucket, store it away for a couple of months and see where the flavor goes.  If it gets worse, dump it, if it gets better, age it until you like it.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to do just that. I've also bought some oak chips too :)

Comment: Honestly, if you have the space and the spare equipment, why the Hell not?  As far as oak, do some searching here to see the recommended oaking dosages so that you don't potentially wind up with oak with a side of beer.

Comment: Is that the actual aquarium heater submerged in the beer?!?

Comment: Erm...... Yup :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to say that looks like the beginning of a pellicle, meaning your beer is infected.  But if you drink it quickly, you may avoid the worst of it.  Best case, it might even taste good!  And NEVER put that heater in your beer!  Put the beer in a tub of water and put the heater in the water.